# How to use NSSet created from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nsset

I have the following core data model:
[image]
[image]

where Person to Codes is a one-to-many relationship.

I have a function which returns a Person record and if the code `person.codes` returns an NSSet of all the codes associated with that Person. The issue that I am having is how to use the NSSet.

`person.codes.allObjects.first` returns this data:

```
<Codes: 0x60000213cb40> (entity: Codes; id: 0xb978dbf34ddb849 <x-coredata://A2B634E4-E136-48E1-B2C5-82B6B68FBE44/Codes/p1> ; data: {
    code = 4LQ;
    number = 1;
    whosAccount = "0xb978dbf34ddb869 <x-coredata://A2B634E4-E136-48E1-B2C5-82B6B68FBE44/Person/p1>";
})
```

I thought if I made `person.codes.allObjects.first` of type `Codes`, I would be able to access the `code` and `number` elements but I get an error: `error: value of type 'Any?' has no member 'number'`

Also, how can I search this data set for a particular code or number.

I appreciate that this is proabably a simple question but have searched and read the documentation to no avail. I suspect that may base knowledge is not sufficient.

## Update

I have a CoreDataHandler class which contains the following code:

```
class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {
    //static let sharedInstance = CoreDataHandler()

    private static func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    static func fetchPerson() -> [Person]? {
        let context = getContext()

        do {
            let persons: [Person] = try context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())
            return persons
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I can fetch a person using:

```
let row = personTableView.selectedRow
let person = CoreDataHandler.fetchPerson()?[row]
```

Comment: All objects takes the NSSet and makes an array

Comment: map it into an array first, if you need an index-based collection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Core Data supports widely native Swift types.

Declare `codes` as `Set<Codes>` in the `Person` class.

It's much more convenient than *typeless* `NSSet`.
You get a strong type and you can apply all native functions like `filter`, `sort`, etc. without type cast.

Comment: I realize that it is probably an obvious question but how do I actually declare `codes` in the `Person` class?

Comment: You have to create the `NSManagedObject` subclasses manually. In the model file in the Entity Inspector change the Codegen popup of all entities to Manual/None, then in Menu Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass create the classes and change the types.

Comment: I have done that and have a Person class which looks like this:`public class Person: NSManagedObject { }`. How do I declare `codes` in that class?

Comment: There are two files per entity. A +CoreDataClass file and a +CoreDataProperties file. The properties are declared in the +CoreDataProperties file.

Comment: In my Person+.. file, I have: `@NSManaged public var codes: Set<Codes>?`. Now in my viewController class, this code works: `let codes = person?.codes;
        let filteredCodes = codes!.filter({ $0.number == 1 });
        print("key for code1= \(filteredCodes)")` and prints out: `key for code1= [<Codes: 0x60000213d360> (entity: Codes; id: 0xe7b68aa93f25f785 <x-coredata://.........> ; data: {
    code = 4LQ;
    number = 1;
    whosAccount = "0xe7b68aa93f25f7a5 <x-coredata://.......>";
})]`. But `filteredCodes.code` is not recognised. How do I get to just the code, 4LQ?

Comment: First of all declare a to-many relationship as non-optional (`Set<Codes>`). Uncheck Optional also in the model file for the relationship. The result of `filter` is an array (note the `[]`), If you want to get one item use `first` (which returns an optional).

Comment: Changed to non-optional and unchecked Optional also but `let filteredCodes = codes!.filter({ $0.number == 1 })` and `let code = filteredCodes.first` both print out the same info: `key for code1= [<Codes: 0x60000213d360> (entity: Codes; id: 0xe7b68aa93f25f785 <x-coredata://A2B634E4-E136-48E1-B2C5-82B6B68FBE44/Codes/p1> ; data: {
    code = 4LQ;
    number = 1;
    whosAccount = "0xe7b68aa93f25f7a5 <x-coredata://A2B634E4-E136-48E1-B2C5-82B6B68FBE44/Person/p1>";
})]`

Comment: No, `let filteredCodes = codes!.first{ $0.number == 1 }`

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder why the autodefined classes after creating an entity doesn't do so. It's the behaviour everyone would expect

Comment: @brainray I found this: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2021/03/31/making-nsfetchrequest-fetchbatchsize-work-with-swift/

Answer (score 4):

```
let codes = person.codes as! Set<Code>
```

Once that is done you can access the properties. Searching can be done by filtering for instance

```
let filteredCodes = codes.filter({ $0.code == "XYZ" })
```

will return all objects that has the code "XYZ". Or to get only one you can use

```
let code = codes.first(where: {$0.id == 1})
```

which will return the first object that has id = 1

A simple example getting all Person objects that has a given code

```
func findWithCode(_ code: String) -> [Person] {
    guard let persons = CoreDataHandler.fetchPerson() else {
        return []
    }

    var result = [Person]()
    for person in persons {
        let codes = person.codes as! Set<Code>
        if codes.contains(where: { $0.code == code }) {
            result.append(person)
        }
    }

    return persons
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I try and typecast the set as `Codes`: Cast from 'NSSet?' to unrelated type 'Codes' always fails`

Comment: Have you tried as a native type `let codes: Set<Codes> = person.codes`?

Comment: If I try `let codes: Set<Codes> = person.codes`, I get this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSSet?' to specified type 'Set<Codes>`

Comment: @pdoak My answer is incorrect in the typecasting, I'll update

Comment: if I try `let codes = person.codes as! [Codes]`, I get this error: `Cast from 'NSSet?' to unrelated type '[Codes]' always fails`

Comment: Ah, you are missing a question mark since your method returns `[Persons]?`, try to change it to `let codes = person?.codes as! [Codes]`. Or `if let codes = person?.codes as! [Codes] {...}`

Comment: I still get the error: `Cast from 'NSSet?' to unrelated type '[Codes]' always fails`

Comment: No, as I am not sure how to do that. My Person class looks like this:`public class Person: NSManagedObject {

}`

Comment: @pdoak I did setup my own version of your model and used that to improve my answer

Comment: this line `let codes = person.codes as! Set<Codes>` would not work for me. The only way I could get it to work was to make this declaration `@NSManaged public var codes: Set<Codes>?` in my Person class extension. I don't understand why cast the NSSet as Codes in my ViewController

Comment: Ok. Well I did create an Xcode project with the same entities as yours and the above code works for me so there is nothing more I can do now. I also tried changing the declaration of codes in the Person class to Set<Codes> and that also worked. Anyway I guess you have a working solution by now using the other answer so all is good

Comment: I do have a working solution but it frustrates that I don’t understand why it wasn’t work